# All elements with the same class are affected by click function

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I modify my code that affects all the elements with the same class In my Jquery to make click effects only to my desired html element (.divCollapsilble)

[This is my site](http://jedllenado.byethost7.com/collapsible/) that shows the effect of my code below

My script.js:

```
// JavaScript Document
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.divCollapsible').hide();
  $('.divToggle').click(function(){
  var location = $(this).parent().parent();

    $('.divCollapsible').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

How can I implement

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your markup so people don't have to go and inspect your site

Comment: why there are down votes???

Comment: This question demonstrates exactly why we need people providing relevant code in the question. The answer would not have been possible with the site in its current state (that is, no longer available), since it depends on knowing the structure of the HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the code like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.divCollapsible').hide();
  $('.divToggle').click(function(){
    $(this).next(".divCollapsible").slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PBbmf/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll need to wait 5min to accept your answer.

Comment: This answer would be better if the HTML necessary were included in the answer. Right now, with the OP's link going to a parking site, this was apparently the result of ESP.

Answer (score 3):

`$(this).siblings('.divCollapsible').slideToggle('slow');` should do. That way you are targeting only siblings of your `.divToggle` with class `.divCollapsible` instead of all collapsible elements on the page.